# Width-only resize with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a webpage that's divided into two columns. I have made these columns resizable. Is there any way to allow only the width to resize, and not height? Also, when I resize one column the width of other column should get resized correspondingly.

**To give information about How I am achieving this at this point of time is:**
On the "resize" event of column1 I am retrieving the width of that column1 & setting width of column2 by subtracting  column1 width from entire webpage width.this is how the second column gets resized correspondingly when I resize the first Column.

**Can anybody tell if this is an appropriate way to do it? 
If not please suggest a better way to do it..thanx in advance :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Resizable widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) has options for `minHeight`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-minHeight)</sup>* and `maxHeight`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-maxHeight)</sup>*. If you set those equal to your viewport height, only the width will be resizable.

```
var wndHeight = $(window).height(); // Use whatever height is appropriate
$('#column1').height(wndHeight)
             .resizable({ minHeight: wndHeight, maxHeight: wndHeight });
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu7NY/).

To resize the other column, you can use the [resize event of the Resizable widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#event-resize), similarly to how you've already described using the stand resize event.

Answer (score 0):

you have tried with the css properties min-height, max-height, min-width and max-width? if your using a plugin, the most common thing is that those properties will work for you as limits for resizing the element

Answer (score 0):

FishBasketGordo's answer didn't work for me for some reason.  I was able to fix the problem by using the ResizableWidget's `resize`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize)</sup>* event.  The following example assumes that you are resizing #target_div, and you want #target_div to maintain the same height (in pixels).

```
var targetHeight = $('#target_div').height(); // Get the height of the object.  This can be done when the window loads.
$('#target_div').resizable({
  resize: function(event, ui) {
    ui.element.css('height', targetHeight);
  },
});
```